# Adding Javascript objects into innerHTML

Tags: javascript, object, innerhtml

Say I create an image object like below. ( `create();` is a function I wrote but I know this function works.)

`var img = create("img", "images/duba.jpg");`

When I try to put this image into the `innerHTML` of another object that's a div, I get this plain text where the image should show up:

`[object HTMLImageElement]`

What's the correct method to insert one object into another like this? I have to think there's a more graceful method than hard-coding the innerHTML with strings, which I've tried successfully.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call `appendChild` to append the DOM element to an existing element.

Answer (score 1):

You should use DOM manipulation methods. E.g.

- [`element.appendChild`  *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.appendChild)
- [`element.insertBefore`   *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.insertBefore)

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use:

```
otherObject.appendChild(img);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are creating an element you can't set it as a node's innerHTML, that takes a string of HTML. Just use DOM manipulation

```
parent.appendChild ( create("img", "images/duba.jpg") );
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `appendChild` method. The `innerHTML` property receives a string, not a DOM element.

https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.appendChild